# Best practice to keep track of timestamps?

Tags: mysql, sql

If have been trying to keep track of multiple timestamps regarding user-related inputs and my idea was that each column is a user_id written as 1234 and when a user does something it adds a timestamp

| used_id | used_id | used_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TIMESTAMP | TIMESTAMP | TIMESTAMP |
| TIMESTAMP | TIMESTAMP | TIMESTAMP |
| TIMESTAMP | TIMESTAMP | TIMESTAMP |

the thing is that when I insert NOW() values for each user_id it shifts it like this

| 1234 | 4321 | 2341 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-19 02:00:00 | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | 2021-04-19 03:00:00 | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | 2021-04-19 04:00:00 |
| 2021-04-20 02:00:00 | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | 2021-04-20 03:00:00 | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | 2021-04-20 04:00:00 |

even tho I want it like this

| 1234 | 4321 | 2341 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-19 02:00:00 | 2021-04-19 03:00:00 | 2021-04-19 04:00:00 |
| 2021-04-20 02:00:00 | 2021-04-20 03:00:00 | 2021-04-20 04:00:00 |

Is there another way to achieve something like this?
Thank you

Comment: Have a column for users and a column for timestamps

Comment: ^^^^ In a single table

Comment: @Strawberry Then I'd need to add a new column for each new timestamp wouldn't I ?

Comment: you have one tablewith tghree columns  id, user_id and timestamo

Comment: You would add a row for each new timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a normalised arrangement:

```
user_id timestamp
   1234 2021-04-19 02:00:00         
   4321 2021-04-19 03:00:00         
   2341 2021-04-19 04:00:00
   1234 2021-04-20 02:00:00     
   4321 2021-04-20 03:00:00     
   2341 2021-04-20 04:00:00
```

or

```
reading_id user_id timestamp
         1    1234 2021-04-19 02:00:00      
         1    4321 2021-04-19 03:00:00      
         1    2341 2021-04-19 04:00:00
         2    1234 2021-04-20 02:00:00  
         2    4321 2021-04-20 03:00:00  
         2    2341 2021-04-20 04:00:00
```

Comment: I am sorry I get what you meant now. I thought I could do something similar to Excel but it seems like it is easier to simply insert the user_id multiple times. Sorry if my question was trivial

Comment: A database table is NOT a spreadsheet!!